# phpBB 3 to bbPress

Tags: plugins, import, bbpress, migration

I am updating a diabetes forum to make it more extensive for which I have previously used phpBB 3. I have decided to use WordPress on the new build and have  installed bbPress, however, I would like to import/transfer the existing users, forums and posts on phpBB into bbPress. There aren't that many of each to do manually, but I would still like to be able to do this manually. I have tried the ForumConverter and WP phpBB Bridge plugins but neither of them worked, so if anybody has any advice or suggestions that would be greatly appreciated.

I don't know if it's because I have downloaded the latest stable version of everything but strangely I don't appear to have any tables with the "bb_" prefix in my database either...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind now. Fortunately (in this case) I have found an alternative solution to bbPress for WordPress - Simple:Press! I personally think that Simple:Press is much better not only because it allowed me to import everything from phpBB very easily but also because it seems much more comprehensive and well put together; - more comparable to phpBB!

So, basically Simple:Press is my answer and in a strange kind way, I'm glad I ran into problems with bbPress!...